# Reloading a custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, loadcontrol

I have a cs class which I use as a control on one of my page. It is like a table with some values. This control is loaded when the page loads. After user does some selection, I need to refresh this control with the new values which I do by assigning it in code behind. My problem is that though I am reassigning some properties, the control which was loaded on the page load, does not refresh, which makes sense. i have tried a few ways but could not figure it out. I am posting it here as I am running short of time and would appreciate it if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling `LoadControl` on `PreInit` and doing so on each postback.

**PreInit:**

Use this event for the following:

- Create or re-create dynamic controls.
- ....

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)